# mysql select and insert safely and quickly with php

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo, insert

I have a simple table, the logic is that before inserting a new row, I should fetch one column from that table. Let me explain:

`table`

```
id    key     groupId      Note
1    00001      1        abd
2    00002      1        aasdas
3    00003      1        aasdas
4    00001      2        q2eqwd
5    00002      2        qwdvvd
6    00003      2        qwrqw
7    00004      2        qwdqdqw
```

You see, key increases like Auto Increment for each groupId.
When group with id 2, wants to add a new note, he should know last key. After finding it, php addes +1 to last key and inserts a new row. I do it like below:

```
$groupId = 2; //for example
$note = $_POST['note'];

$select = $db -> prepare("SELECT key FROM table where groupId = :groupId ORDER BY id DESC limit 1");
$select -> bindValue(":groupId", $groupId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$select -> execute();
$fetch = $select -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$lastKey = $fetch['key']+1;

$insert = "INSERT INTO table (key, groupId, note) VALUES(:key, :groupId, :note)";

$ins = $db -> prepare($insert);
$insert -> bindValue(":key", $lastKey, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$insert -> bindValue(":groupId", $groupId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$insert -> bindValue(":note", $note, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

This method works good for me, but I am afraid of is here will be any conflict while fetching last key from table? Because, at the same time, 10 user with same groupId can add a new row. May php fetch same key to 3 users with group ID 2 at the same time?

Is there any quickly and safely way?

Comment: There will be a conflict. That's why `key` should be an `auto_increment` and you shouldn't do it via PHP.

Comment: but keys can repeat for different groupId. There can be 10 same key with differenf GroupId

Comment: It's a fact that you cannot guarantee uniqueness if you generate anything using any programming language (for inserting). If you were to do this in any language, you face the same problem. This brings us back to analyzing what it is that you want to do. You have a table, table has key, groupId and note. But why does this `key` have to be sequential in any way? You see, the problem you have actually comes from sub-optimal data model. Using PHP to generate a sequence like that is difficult because you need to deal with concurrency yourself, which means you take that away from MySQL.

Comment: I think you're confusing data storeage with data retrieval and display.

Comment: Eeach user's key have to start from 1 and should increase like auto_increment.  This is my boss'es ask. and we have to find every note by using key.  Of course I Can give an increment keys using loop. but in this case it will impossible to find note by Key from database. Except this one if the row will be deleted,  there will by another problem. So, that is why I have to keep keys in database

Comment: `Eeach user's key have to start from 1 and should increase like auto_increment` -> but auto_increment deals with concurrency and you don't. Is there any chance that this problem occurs because your boss wants nice and "pretty" sequential numbers with no gaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `AUTO_INCREMENT` using MyISAM.

From MySQL [Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html):

> For MyISAM and BDB tables you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a
>   secondary column in a multiple-column index. ... This is useful when you want to put data into ordered groups.

Otherwise, you should set the value in your insert query with a subquery like `SELECT MAX(key) + 1 FROM table WHERE groupID = 1` and read back the value.